# Excel: Multiple Substitute without nesting and without VBA

Tags: excel, substitution

I have cells that have data that I want to remove. The cells typically look like this:

```
alm1 105430_65042M
1993_5689IB
ALM99 3455 344C
0001_4555Alm5
```

Some but not all of the cells contain text like "almj" where "j" is a positive integer. I want to remove that part. I want the output to look like this:

```
105430_65042M
1993_5689IB
3455 344C
0001_4555
```

So something like this works

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"alm1",""),"ALM99",""),"Alm5","")
```

But for my full data set I would need this to be several-hundred-deep nested function because my "alm" is sometimes in capital letters and sometimes not and the integer can vary from 1 to 100. This seems like a painful way to do this.

Is there a way that I can tell it to look for text listed in a column (so I can have a column in a different sheet that just goes from alm, alm1, ..., alm100 ) and then also ask it to ignore capitalization and then just replace stuff?

I tried referencing a column $M$1:$M$100 in the second argument of the function substitute but it's not working.

```
SUBSTITUTE(A2,$M$1:$M$100,"")
```

Where the column M contains "alm" alm1", ..., "alm100" etc.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you, it returned expected results on your provided sample data:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*alm*")=0,A2,TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2&" ",MID(A2&" ",SEARCH("alm",A2),FIND(" ",A2&" ",SEARCH("alm",A2))),"")))
```

Comment: Thank you!! That works perfectly! I'll leave the accept for a day in case someone comes up with another way to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I did edit the formula to make it shorter and more streamlined, though the execution is still identical

Answer (score 1):

Excel has lousy string-handling capabilities.  Regular expressions would make this task much easier.

In JavaScript, it's as simple as:

```
string.replace(/ *alm[0-9]+ */gi,'')
```

This does a global (g) case-insensitive (i) search of everything with:

- 0 or more spaces

  followed by "alm" (in any case)

  followed by 1 or more numbers

  followed by 0 or more spaces

You can paste your data in the **HTML** box in this fiddle, and it will fix it:

**http://jsfiddle.net/xs71bvan/2/**